# How to inject a TomEE Resource into my Spring application's context?

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, cdi, apache-tomee

I'm trying to make use of ActiveMQ built into the TomEE container. I can see in the startup's console output Resource MyJmsConnectionFactory is provisioned by TomEE. But I can't seem to inject it into my Spring Bean(s). The documentation about CDI and Spring together is lacking. Even the explanatory documentation on the TomEE site is lacking. I can only find how to accomplish making use of TomEE's JMS if I write a more pure JEE application, but not how to integrate these container resources with the Spring Framework.

If anyone has any link or tips to enlighten me, this is the 1st time I'm asking a question on StackOverflow instead of finding the question already asked (and answered here) which is strange because the CDI/Spring chatter I'm finding on the Web goes back to 2011; even 2009. What am I not-in-the-know about that the world community of technologists aren't discussing this problem and solution more often online?

Answer (score 0):

I got unblocked by giving up on CDI. Instead of dependency injecting the ActiveMQ bean into my Spring webapp but created by the Tomcat container, I just created my own ActiveMQ connection bean myself in my code.

I'm using Spring 5.0.3-RELEASE and activemq-client 5.15.3. I didn't need everything in the maven shaded uber jar activemq-all.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

  @Bean
  public SingleConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
      ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
      ((ActiveMQConnectionFactory) connectionFactory)
            // See http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html why we set trusted packages
            .setTrustedPackages(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("com.mydomain", "java.util")));
    return new SingleConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
}

  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
      return new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public Queue myQueue() throws JMSException {
      Connection connection = connectionFactory().createConnection();
      connection.start();
      Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      Queue queue = session.createQueue("message-updates");
      return queue;
  }
}

@Component
public class MyQueueImpl implements MyQueue {

  @Inject
  private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

  @Inject
  private Queue myQueue;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
   jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(JmsTemplate.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT);
  }

  @Override
  public void enqueue(Widget widget) {
      jmsTemplate.send(myQueue, new MessageCreator() {
          @Override
          public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
              return session.createObjectMessage(widget);
          }
      });
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<Widget> dequeue() {
    Optional<Widget> widget = Optional.empty();
    ObjectMessage message = (ObjectMessage) jmsTemplate.receive(myQueue);
    try {
        if (message != null) {
            widget = Optional.ofNullable((Widget) message.getObject());
            message.acknowledge();
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new UncategorizedJmsException(e);
    }

    return widget;
  }
}
```

This is the webpage that helped me unblock myself - https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-integration/jms-template.html